# How to implement code optimization using LLVM of c++ code in python code?

Tags: python, c++, llvm, llvmlite

I want to implement code optimization for c++ code, I am implementing an API using python which receives optimized code and does some transformation to be input for a deep learning model.
My question:
How to implement code optimization using LLVM of c++ code in python code? Is llvmLite able to implement this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use clang?

Comment: do you mean: using clang and then exporting the output to python?? or there is a way to call clang from python and compile the c++ code?

Comment: No idea what you're trying to do, but if you need to compile c++ code then the easiest route would seem to be to use a c++ compiler

Comment: I want to create optimized c++ code using LLVM and then use this optimized code to be input for a deep learning model. could I use LLVM in python ??